# Refine Enumerable LINQ WHERE statement with repeated parameters

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have the following code to return all records that has the contract expiration in determined days:

```
return pSource
                .Where(q => 
                    q.StaffContracts.OrderByDescending(p => p.SignedDate).FirstOrDefault().Timespan.HasValue &&
                    q.StaffContracts.OrderByDescending(p => p.SignedDate).FirstOrDefault().SignedDate.HasValue &&
                    (q.StaffContracts.OrderByDescending(p => p.SignedDate).FirstOrDefault().SignedDate.Value.AddMonths( q.StaffContracts.OrderByDescending(p => p.SignedDate).FirstOrDefault().Timespan.Value)
                    - now).TotalDays <= value);
```

As you can see, `q.StaffContracts.OrderByDescending(p => p.SignedDate).FirstOrDefault()` is repeated many times. Is there a way to shorten this statement? And what is its equivalence SQL statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about doing it this way?

```
return
    from q in pSource
    let sc = q.StaffContracts
        .OrderByDescending(p => p.SignedDate)
        .FirstOrDefault()
    where sc != null
    let ts = sc.Timespan
    let sd = sc.SignedDate
    where ts.HasValue
    where sd.HasValue
    where (sd.Value.AddMonths(ts.Value) - now).TotalDays <= value
    select q;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can turn it into a method body.. it returns `bool`. Might not be a bad idea to check for `null` too:

```
return pSource.Where(q => {
    var contract = q.StaffContracts.OrderByDescending(p => p.SignedDate).FirstOrDefault();

    if (contract == null)
        return false; // returns nothing

    return contract.Timespan.HasValue &&
           contract.SignedDate.HasValue &&
           (contract.SignedDate.Value.AddMonths(contract.Timespan.Value) - now)
           .TotalDays <= value;
});
```

I'm going to go out on a limb and say this will boost your performance by a lot.. having only one order call.

Comment: Thank you, I receive the syntax error at the lambda operation: `A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree`. How can I solve this? Sorry I am new to LINQ.

Comment: Ah. That's a problem. LINQ is not directly a SQL technology.. it is utilised by ORMs such as LINQ-to-SQL, Entity Framework, NHibernate, etc to create SQL. It does this by visiting each node in a lambda expression to generate SQL. What I've given you is LINQ.. but its not a lambda expression.. its a full method body. This won't be able to be converted to SQL unfortunately.